# Convert pandas datetime time difference values from days to years

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a datetime value (date of an event) that I created by importing a date value from a csv file. I then tried to calculate that person's age by subtracting the datetime of the event from the datetime of their date of birth. This gives me an answer in days - but I'd like it in years.

To import the data from an excel csv file I used this:

```
Patients = pandas.read_csv("Patients_SN.csv", parse_dates=True) 
Patients['dateofbirth'] = pandas.to_datetime(Patients['dateofbirth'], format='%d/%m/%Y')
```

I then merged the patient data with another (event) dataset called Transitions3 so that each event has the person's date of birth in a column called 'dateofbirth'.

I've been able to get a number (in days) that represents the age of the person at the time of the event using the following:

```
Transitions3['AgeAtFirstEvent']=(Transitions3['FirstEventDate']-Transitions3['dateofbirth'])
```

As I said - this gives me the answer in days

```
1782 days 00:00:00.000000000
```

- but i want it in years (and fractions of years e.g. 45.5 years).

I've tried using the following code to change it to years

```
Transitions3['AgeAtFirstDial']= pandas.to_datetime(Transitions3['AgeAtFirstDial'], unit="y")
```

but I get this error: 
ValueError: cannot cast unit y

have also tried:

```
Transitions3['Age1stDial']=Transitions3['AgeAtFirstDial'].total_years()
```

but i get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-22-3dc3b7338471>", line 1, in <module>
    Transitions3['Age1stDial']=Transitions3['AgeAtFirstDial'].total_years()

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 4376, in __getattr__
    return object.__getattribute__(self, name)

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'total_years'
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so people can reproduce your error and help you better

Answer (score 2):

I think the output of the subtraction is a timedelta series. In that case, you can convert it with the following.

```
Transitions3['AgeAtFirstEvent'] / np.timedelta64(1, 'Y')
```

You can read more about it [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timedeltas.html).